# Railsアプリのファイル配置

Tags: ruby-on-rails

ユーザーが手書きの画像をアップロードし、サーバーに置かれている画像の中からそれに類似した画像を表示するアプリを作りたいです。

Rails側には大量の画像と、そこから類似画像を探すプログラムのバイナリが必要になりますが、 http://railsdoc.com/rails_base の表の中で言えばどこに置くのが適切ですか？それとも新しいディレクトリを作るべきですか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

それだけの情報では、どこに置くべきと一概には言えないのですが、
仮に私がどうしても Rails プロジェクトの下に置くならば、以下のようにします。

- 画像データ: `public/` の下
- バイナリプログラム: `script/server` の下

ただそれぞれの性質を考えると、Rails プロジェクトの外に置いたほうが良いようにも感じます。

- 画像データ: `/var/db/my_service/` のような場所において、そのパスを環境変数で Rails プロジェクトに伝える
- バイナリプログラム: `/usr/local/bin/` などの PATH の通った場所にインストールする

Answer (score 0):

わたしなら、、

画像は、位置をmodelに記載して、どこかに配置する
バイナリについては、rbならcontrollersでしょうが、ネイティブなら、binディレクトリとか作って参照する